# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.users[index].uses1.length')

Tags: arrays, react-native, frontend

Hey I am trying to write multiple conditional statement for styling based on the selected array length. Unfortunately it isn't recognizing the syntax and giving me the error on the title. I just want it to recognise the concerned array since I am writting a Flatlist for multiple user array items. can anyone help, please?

Code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image, ImageBackground, PixelRatio, Platform, UIManager, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import DropDownItem from 'react-native-drop-down-item';


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={

        users: [{

            uses1: '- Bottles',
            uses2: '- Cans',
            uses3: '- Jars',
            expanded: false
        },
        {
            uses1: '- Grays',
            uses2: '- Lines',
            uses3: '- Interior',
            expanded: false
        },
        {
            uses1: '- Live',
            uses2: '- Cutter',
            uses3: '- Riser',
            expanded: false
        },
    ]

    }
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }

      }


      changeLayout =  ({index}) => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);

     this.setState(({ users }) => ({
        users: users.map((s, idx) => 
          idx === index ? {...s, expanded: !this.state.users[index].expanded} : {...s, expanded: false})
      }));
      console.log(this.state.users[index].expanded)



      };
//if uses1 + uses1.left + uses2 + uses2.left + uses3 + use3.left <=x then stay up or uses 3 go down

      getUses2style(index){
        if(this.state.users[index].uses1.length<=12)
        {return{ 
          fontSize: 17,
          left:100,
          top:-125,
          color: 'white',
          padding: 10}}
          else if(12<this.state.users[index].uses1.length<=22)
          {return{ 
            fontSize: 17,
            left:200,
            top:-125,
            color: 'white',
            padding: 10}}
      }

       render() {

//create an expand state for all materials in this.state
    return (
      // Remain Category image and CSS
      // add search bar
      <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor:'#262A2C',
        flex:1
      }}>
      <FlatList
     style={{marginTop:80,}}
        data={this.state.users}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
       <View>

          <ImageBackground

          source={require('./Icons/error.png')} 
        //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
          style={{ 

            resizeMode: 'contain',

          position:'relative',

          width: wp('100%'), 
          left: wp('0%'),
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: 'grey',
          padding: hp('6%'),
          }}
        >
       <View
            style={{
              flex:1,
             height:hp('19%'),
             width: wp('100%'),
             //height:hp('21%'),

              borderBottomColor: 'grey',

            }}>




              <Text 
              style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',
               fontSize: 22, 
               left:item.name.length<=5 ? wp('32.5%'):wp('27.5%'),
               top:hp('-9.5%'),


               }}>
               Stands
               </Text>
              <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 25, 
                top: hp('-25%'),
                left:wp('80%')

              }}>
              History
              </Text>


          </View>





   </ImageBackground>
   <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8}  
   onPress={() => {

             this.changeLayout({index})

              }} 

    style={{ padding: 10,

    backgroundColor:'black',

    left:wp('-10.9%'),
    top:hp('0%'),
    width: wp('120%'),
    height:hp('5%')}}>
   <Image
               style={{
               width:wp('9%'),
               height:hp('4.5%'),
              tintColor:'white',
              left:250,
              top:-10
               //tintColor:'#81F018'
               }}
               source={item.expanded ? require('./Icons/arrowDown.png') : require('./Icons/arrowUp.png') }/>
</TouchableOpacity>
<View style={{ height: item.expanded ? null : 0, overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor:'black' }}>
            <Text 
            style={{
               fontSize: 17,
               left:150,
               top:-10,
               color: 'turquoise',
               padding: 10}}>
          Specs
            </Text>
            <View>

            </View>
            <Text 
            style={{
               fontSize: 17,
               left:125,
               top:-90,
               color: 'turquoise',
               padding: 10}}>
          Common uses
            </Text>
            <Text
             style={{
              fontSize: 17,
              left:0,
              top:-85,
              color: 'white',
              padding: 10}}>
{item.uses1}
            </Text>
            <Text
             style={
              this.getUses2style(index)}>
{item.uses2}
            </Text>
          </View>  
    </View>
        )}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Camille, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is here,

```
getUses2style({ index }) {  ... }
```

Here you are actually destructuring the params passed to `getUses2style` function, so the function is not able to recognise that `index`,

You simply need to do this,

```
getUses2style(index) {  ... }   //without `{}`
```

Comment: Hey ravibagul, I've already tried that and I've tried again recently, it did not work unfortunately

Comment: Should I be mapping it maybe

Comment: Can you post complete component code so that I can review it?

Comment: I think the problem is here, `style={
              this.getUses2style({index})}`. Here also you need to remove `{}` like `style={
              this.getUses2style(index)}`

Comment: Yeah i saw that, it was just a mistake when i copy and pasted it. Its actually not the solution since i still get the same error. I've edited the post again to correct it

Comment: Do the same changes for `changeLayout`.

Comment: Also you need to bind `this` to `getUses2style` in a constructor like `this.getUses2style = this.getUses2style.bind(this)` or you can use arrow function like `getUses2style = (index) => {...}`

Comment: Hey actually binding is not required here, it works without it. The truth is that I ahd a long array list where i had some index that didnt have uses in them. I actually created a mock to postr here . So i had to add uses to all other arrays and it worked.

Comment: So it was working initially just that i didn't add uses to the other arrays. But you really invest your time to help and your answer is correct anyways for the given post so i am giving you the point. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Once you tested that 
`this.state.users[index].uses1.length<=12` is false (and you are in the first `else` statement), you don't need anymore test it again, It still is false, and if you still want test it, I think you should mostly test
 using the following syntax : `( x < a && a < y )`, I don´t think triple operator are supported.

Comment: actually it works fine if I replace [index] with [0] even with triple operator. It just doesnt recognise [index]

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the index inside the function. Are you sure you are sending the parameter as object. If not then remove the `{}` from index and use that directly.

```
getUses2style( index ) {
alert(index)//Make sure it is not undefined
                if (this.state.users[index].uses1.length <= 12) {
                    return {
                        fontSize: 17,
                        left: 100,
                        top: -125,
                        color: 'white',
                        padding: 10
                    }
                } else if (12 < this.state.users[index].uses1.length <= 22) {
                    return {
                        fontSize: 17,
                        left: 200,
                        top: -125,
                        color: 'white',
                        padding: 10
                    }
                } else if (22 < this.state.users[index].uses1.length <= 42) {
                    return {
                        fontSize: 17,
                        left: 400,
                        top: -125,
                        color: 'white',
                        padding: 10
                    }
                }
            }
```